# How to get MD5 hash of a string using Jinja2?

Tags: jinja2

In `Jinja2`, is there any way to get the MD5 hash value of a given string?

I know I can do this in Python. But how can do the same in Jinja2?

import hashlib
print(hashlib.md5(b"Hello World").hexdigest())

thanks

Comment: There is no built-in MD5 filter in Jinja. You would need to write a custom filter and provide that to your template. This is all described [in the documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#writing-filters).